# This returns NONE. Am I nesting incorrectly?

Tags: python

`behavioural_level` is defined as raw_input 1, 2 or 3.
What's going on here?

```
def summary_behaviour(x):
    if behaviour_level == 1:
        x = random.randint(0,1)
        if x == 0:
            return " "+str(first_name)+" has a rather "+str(shy[random.randint(0,(len(shy)-1))])+" personality. This has certain advantages. One is that "+str(he_she(gender))+" doesn't easily "+str(lose_focus[random.randint(0,(len(lose_focus)-1))])+": however, "+str(he_she(gender))+" can be a litte quiet at times." 
        else:
            if x == 1:
                return " Because of "+str(first_name)+"'s "+str(shy[random.randint(0,len(shy)-1)])+" character "+str(he_she(gender))+" can be a little quiet sometimes. On the plus side, however, "+str(he_she(gender))+" doesn't "+str(lose_focus[random.randint(0,len(lose_focus)-1)])+" very easily."
    elif behaviour_level == 2:
        x = random.randint(2,3)
        if x == 2:
            return str(first_name)+" is usually quite "+str(loud[random.randint(0,(len(loud)-1))])+" in class, and this has advantages and disadvantages. "+str(first_name)+" loves to involved and enjoys speaking, but sometimes "+str(hes_shes(gender))+" too "+str(loud[random.randint(0,(len(loud)-1))])+" to fully concentrate. This is common though. "
        else:
            if x == 3:
                return " Because of "+str(first_name)+"'s "+str(loud[random.randint(0,len(loud)-1)])+" character "+str(he_she(gender))+" is "+str(adjective(int(science_level)))+" at speaking up and volunteering. Occasionally, "+str(his_her(gender))+" "+ str(loud[random.randint(0,len(loud)-1)])+ " nature can cuase "+str(him_her(gender))+ " to "+str(lose_focus[random.randint(0,len(lose_focus)-1)])+" but, that's fairly normal at "+str(his_her(gender))+" age."
    else:
        if behaviour_level == 3:
            x = random.randint(4,5)
            if x == 4:
                return " I would descirbe "+str(fisrt_name)+" as a "+(str(well_mannered[random.randint(0,len(well-mannered)-1)]))+" child who is easy to teach. Rarely is "+str(he_she(gender))+" too "+str(loud[random.randint(0,(len(loud)-1))])+" to focus or too "+str(shy[random.randint(0,(len(shy)-1))])+" too speak up."
            else:
                if x == 5: 
                    return str(first_name)+" a "+ (str(well_ma
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your nests are fine.

`raw_input()` returns a string. It doesn't look like you have converted it into an integer, so your function goes into the first `else:` bit of your if/else statement, because `behaviour_level != 1` (but rather it equals `"1"`)

Next, `if behaviour_level == 3:`. As the input is a string, not an integer, this is `not True`. And as there is no `else`, the function defaults to return `None`.

To fix this, you can use the `int()` function, which converts a string to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
`int(behaviour_level) == 1,2 or 3` 

to compare 
as 1 2 and 3 are integers and raw_input would return a string.

Also, Instead of doing

```
else:
   if condition:
     """statements"""
```

You can simply use:

```
elif condition:
    """statements"""
```